# save two list in one json file

Tags: python, json, selenium

I'm getting data with two lists and I want to save both of them in one single json file can someone help me.
I'm using selenium

```
def get_name(self):
        name = []
        name = self.find_elements_by_class_name ('item-desc')
        price = []
        price = self.find_elements_by_class_name ('item-goodPrice')
        for names in name :
            names = (names.text)
            #print names
        for prices in price :
            prices = (prices.text)
            #print price
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a dictionary and then JSON `dumps`

An example could be:

```
import json

def get_name(self):
    names = [ name.text for name in self.find_elements_by_class_name('item-desc') ]
    prices = [ price.text for price in self.find_elements_by_class_name('item-goodPrice')]
    with open('output-file-name.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps({'names': names, 'prices': prices}))
```

EDIT: In the first version of  the answer I was only creating the JSON, if you want to create a file as well, you should include what suggested by @Andersson comment

Comment: I try it, it  work but when I try to saved using the follow script i had a :TypeError: <function dumps at 0x7f2671d9c500> is not JSON serializable
                json_data = json.dumps({'names': names, 'prices': prices})
  with open('data.txt','w') as outfile:
   json.dump(json.dumps, outfile)

Comment: @MedDahas, There is a mistake in your code: you should use `json.dump(json_dumps, outfile)` instead of `json.dump(json.dumps, outfile)` .. Also you might need `outfile.write(json_dumps)` to write your `json` into file